# Fatal exception : AsyncTask #1 Android weather app

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-asynctask, weather-api

I am having issue with this Weather App. Apparently there is some null string but I am just a beginner in android studio and I am not sure where. The app crashes and does not even load. The code is written in Java and is for Android mobile phone use.

Here is my **Main Activity** :

```
package com.example.theweatherapp;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.InputType;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpHost;
import org.apache.http.HttpRequest;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.HttpStatus;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest;
import org.apache.http.conn.ClientConnectionManager;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpParams;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext;
import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import Data.CityPreference;
import Data.JSONWeatherParser;
import Data.WeatherHttpClient;
import Model.Weather;
import Tool.Tools;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView cityName;
    private TextView temp;
    private ImageView iconView;
    private TextView description;
    private TextView humidity;
    private TextView pressure;
    private TextView wind;
    private TextView sunrise;
    private TextView sunset;
    private TextView updated;

    Weather weather = new Weather();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        cityName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mestoText);
        iconView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
        temp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.teplotaText);
        description = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mrakText);
        humidity = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.vlhkostText);
        pressure = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tlakText);
        wind = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.vitrText);
        sunrise = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.SvitaniText);
        sunset = (TextView) findViewById((R.id.SoumrakText));
        updated = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.AktualizaceText);

        CityPreference cityPreference = new CityPreference(MainActivity.this);

        renderWeatherData(cityPreference.getCity());

    }
    public void renderWeatherData (String city)
    {
        WeatherTask weatherTask = new WeatherTask();
        weatherTask.execute(new String[]{city + "&APPID=" + Tools.API_KEY + "&units=metric"});
    }
    private class DownloadImageAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap>
    {
        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
            return downloadImage(params[0]);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
            iconView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }

        private Bitmap downloadImage(String code)
        {
            try {
                URL url = new URL(Tools.ICON_URL + code + ".png");
                Log.d("Data : ", url.toString());
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url
                        .openConnection();
                connection.setDoInput(true);
                connection.connect();
                InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
                Bitmap currentBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
                return currentBitmap;
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
        }


    }
    private class WeatherTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Weather>{
        //check this wrong thread
        @SuppressLint("WrongThread")
        @Override
        protected Weather doInBackground(String... params) {

            String data = ( (new WeatherHttpClient().getWeatherData(params[0])));

            weather = JSONWeatherParser.getWeather(data);
            weather.iconData = weather.currentCondition.getIcon();

            Log.v("Data: ", weather.currentCondition.getDescription());

            new DownloadImageAsyncTask().execute(weather.iconData);

            return weather;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Weather weather) {
            super.onPostExecute(weather);

            DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getTimeInstance();
            String sunriseDate = dateFormat.format(new Date(weather.location.getSunrise()));
            String sunsetDate = dateFormat.format(new Date(weather.location.getSunset()));
            String updateDate = dateFormat.format(new Date(weather.location.getLastupdate()));

            DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.#");
            String tempFormat = decimalFormat.format(weather.currentCondition.getTemperature());

            cityName.setText(weather.location.getCity() + "," + weather.location.getCountry());
            temp.setText("" + tempFormat + "°C");
            humidity.setText("Vlhkost: " +  weather.currentCondition.getHumidity() + "%");
            pressure.setText("Tlak: " + weather.currentCondition.getPressure() + "hPa");
            wind.setText("Vítr: " + weather.wind.getSpeed() + "mps");
            sunrise.setText("Svítání: " + sunriseDate );
            sunset.setText("Stmívání " + sunsetDate);
            updated.setText("Naposledy aktualizováno: " + updateDate);
            description.setText("Podmínky: " + weather.currentCondition.getCondition() + "(" + weather.currentCondition.getDescription()+")");

        }

    }
    private void showInputDialog()
    {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        builder.setTitle("Změnit město");

        final EditText cityInput = new EditText(MainActivity.this);
        cityInput.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
        cityInput.setHint("Brno,CZ");
        builder.setView(cityInput);
        builder.setPositiveButton("Submit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                CityPreference cityPreference = new CityPreference(MainActivity.this);
                cityPreference.setCity((cityInput.getText().toString()));

                String newCity = cityPreference.getCity();

                renderWeatherData(newCity);
            }
        });
        builder.show();
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id =item.getItemId();
        if(id == R.id.change_mesto)
        {
            showInputDialog();
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

And here is my **JSONParser** :

```
package Data;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import Model.Location;
import Model.Weather;
import Tool.Tools;

public class JSONWeatherParser {

    public static Weather getWeather(String data){
        Weather weather = new Weather();
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(data);
            Location place = new Location();

            JSONObject coordObj = Tools.getObject("coord", jsonObject);
            place.setLat(Tools.getFloat("lat",coordObj));
            place.setLon(Tools.getFloat("lon",coordObj));

            //sys
            JSONObject sysObj = Tools.getObject("sys", jsonObject);
            place.setCountry(Tools.getString("country", sysObj));
            place.setLastupdate(Tools.getInt("dt", jsonObject));
            place.setSunrise(Tools.getInt("sunrise", sysObj));
            place.setSunset(Tools.getInt("sunset", sysObj));
            place.setCity(Tools.getString("name", jsonObject));
            weather.location = place;

            //weather
            JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("weather");
            JSONObject jsonWeather = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
            weather.currentCondition.setWeatherId(Tools.getInt("id",jsonWeather));
            weather.currentCondition.setDescription(Tools.getString("description",jsonWeather));
            weather.currentCondition.setCondition(Tools.getString("main",jsonWeather));
            weather.currentCondition.setIcon(Tools.getString("icon",jsonWeather));

            JSONObject mainObj = Tools.getObject("main", jsonObject);
            weather.currentCondition.setHumidity(Tools.getInt("humidity", mainObj));
            weather.currentCondition.setPressure(Tools.getInt("pressure", mainObj));
            weather.currentCondition.setMinTemp(Tools.getFloat("temp_min", mainObj));
            weather.currentCondition.setMaxTemp(Tools.getFloat("temp_max", mainObj));
            weather.currentCondition.setTemperature(Tools.getFloat("temp", mainObj));

            JSONObject windObj = Tools.getObject("wind", jsonObject);
            weather.wind.setSpeed(Tools.getFloat("speed",windObj));
            weather.wind.setDeg(Tools.getFloat("deg",windObj));

            JSONObject cloudObj = Tools.getObject("clouds", jsonObject);
            weather.clouds.setPrecipitation(Tools.getInt("all",cloudObj));

            return weather;

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }


    }
}
```

**Error Log:**

```
2019-12-11 11:12:03.183 8902-8949/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
    Process: com.example.theweatherapp, PID: 8902
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
        at android.os.AsyncTask$4.done(AsyncTask.java:399)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:383)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:252)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:271)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:289)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.length()' on a null object reference
        at org.json.JSONTokener.nextCleanInternal(JSONTokener.java:121)
        at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:98)
        at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:164)
        at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:181)
        at Data.JSONWeatherParser.getWeather(JSONWeatherParser.java:16)
        at com.example.theweatherapp.MainActivity$WeatherTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:131)
        at com.example.theweatherapp.MainActivity$WeatherTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:123)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.call(AsyncTask.java:378)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:289) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
```

EDIT:
Also adding my WeatherHttpClient code :

```
package Data;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.Buffer;

import Tool.Tools;

public class WeatherHttpClient {

    public String getWeatherData(String place) {
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        InputStream inputStream = null;

        try {
            connection =(HttpURLConnection) (new URL(Tools.BASE_URL + place + "&APPID="+  Tools.API_KEY)).openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();


            //read the response
            StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
            inputStream=connection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            String line = null;
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine())!=null){
                stringBuffer.append(line + "\r\n");
            }

            inputStream.close();
            connection.disconnect();

            return stringBuffer.toString();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;

    }
}
```

Comment: `String data = ( (new WeatherHttpClient().getWeatherData(params[0])));` this line returns null.  I suggest you add break points and some logging. A side note : The stacktrace tells you everything you need to know for this crash

Comment: I am pretty sure there is a problem with the URL connection, do you think so ?

Comment: `JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(data);` fails because `data` is null which is caused by `WeatherHttpClient.getWeatherData(String place)` has IOException.

Comment: "I am pretty sure there is a problem with the URL connection" - then verify this?